# why I don't need to import related modules?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm new to React, sorry if my questions sound dumb. I'm using `npx create-react-app` to create React app. But I don't know what's going on behind the scenes:

Q1-If I throw an error in a component like:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
...
render() {
    throw new Error("something went wrong");
}
```

I didn't import the Error name feature from any modules, where does `Error` come from? How could I use it directly without importing any related modules like:

```
import Error from "XXX";
```

Q2-When an react app is created, there is a test file called app.test.js, inside this file, there is a function called `it()` as"

```
it('renders without crashing', () => {
    ...
});
```

so where does `it` from? and again why I doesn't need to import any module to use it?

Answer (score 3):

`Error` is JavaScript's default object, you can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error).

`it` is the global variable of jest framework.see [this](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/api#testname-fn-timeout).

You don't have to import the global variables and methods which the framework or language provides.

Answer (score 0):

**Error** is pure JS functionality which is why you don't need to import as it part of your javaScript engine.

Learn more about [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error)

**It** is part of your test framework. If you are using Jest/jasmine whatever. Whenever you run test cases, all test frameworks method is globally available in your current browser session where test cases are running. so does not require.